# Run Swarm but don't store any data

Tags: swarm

I've just set up Swarm. It's amazing.

My domain names now serve swarm pages.

http://eth.ie/bzz:/75de632463a8ea86ce859945e74a502f4cea67e8cdf4c8ced5712621c38a7578/

http://ethereum.ie/bzz:/45238c8c4330b1d64068b0c795e653a3d99a5219b3b0e0437bafc3ef58b74668/

The purpose of my server is to be a gateway that serves pages and do nothing else.

So how can I prevent my server from eating up disk space? (i.e. run Swarm in a mode that it doesn't write anything)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So how can I prevent my server from eating up disk space?

There is a JSON configuration file in your bzz directory. You can set the two relevant storage capacity options to a custom value.

You find this in [the relevant section of the swarm guide](http://swarm-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/runninganode.html#storage-parameters)

Note: Zero memory cache size (`CacheCapacity`) is not going to work. Set that to at least a decent value of a few hundred.

> (i.e. run Swarm in a mode that it doesn't write anything)

It's not a good idea to not write anything. You can set `DbCapacity` to an acceptable value c (then the disk space used by Swarm is estimated at roughly `c * 4Kb` with some added `O(logn)` overhead). Using c = 5000 will take up roughly 25Mb on disk.

Comment: Dude, that's really really helpful. Thanks. In the time it took to check back here, I hacked it by creating a pseudo-partition. `sudo mkdir /bzz   #mount point for the img`
`sudo chown eamorr:eamorr /bzz`

`sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/bzz.img bs=1 count=0 seek=1G`
`ls -altr /bzz.img`
`sudo mkfs /bzz.img`
`sudo mount -o loop /bzz.img /bzz`

`#Add to fstab:`
`/bzz.img /bzz ext4      loop    0 0`